# Prove that the set of nonprime numbers $>0$ is a spectrum

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

$\textbf{6.10 Exercise.}$ A set $M$ of natural numbers is called a $\textit{spectrum}$ if there is a symbol set $S$ and an $S$-sentence $\varphi$ such that
$$M=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid\varphi\text{ has a model containing exactly }n\text{ elements}\}.$$
Show: (d) the set of nonprime numbers $>0$ is a spectrum.

This is an exercise from Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic, I did all the others with some help, but I don't know exactly how to solve this one.

Comment: One possible solution is to think about (unital) rings. Can you think of a property that can only be satistied for rings of a non-prime order?

Comment: As every ring with unity that has prime order is commutative, so could I get a non-commutative ring? @TimSeifert, so
$\varphi = \bigwedge \Phi_{\text{ring}} \wedge \exists v_0\exists v_1\neg(v_0\cdot v_1 \equiv v_1 \cdot v_0)$

Comment: that won't work, since for example any ring of size $p^2$ for $p$ a prime is necessarily commutative. a different approach, which I think @TimSeifert was going for, is that every ring of prime size is an integral domain. now, given a non-prime, can you find a ring of that size that is not an integral domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an argument that generalizes nicely to similar sets in place of the composites, at the cost of resulting in less natural structures:

Take as our language $\{U,V,f\}$ where $U,V$ are unary relation symbols and $f$ is a binary function symbol. Now we can whip up a sentence in this language which intuitively says that the domain is a "nondegenerate rectangle" with sides corresponding to $U$ and $V$ and "coordinatized" by $f$:

> $U$ and $V$ each hold of at least two elements, their intersection has exactly one element, and for each $x$ there is exactly one pair $(a,b)$ such that $U(a), V(b)$, and $f(a,b)=x$.

While for this particular problem the ring theoretic strategy suggested in the comments is much nicer, the above brute-force approach generalizes immediately to more complicated sets like "all numbers which can be written as a product of seventeen numbers $>1$" (just use seventeen unary predicates and have $f$ be seventeen-ary). See also [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4485033/28111) for a more difficult extension. Finally, this way of thinking is the first step towards proving that every $\mathsf{NEXPTIME}$-decidable set is a spectrum (the converse is also true, but this is the hard direction).

The survey paper [*Fifty years of the spectrum problem*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5495) (Durand/Jones/Makowsky/More) may be of interest.

Comment: Why do you care what number of elements $U$ and $V$ have in common?

Comment: @tomasz It's mathematically unnecessary, it's just there so the "rectangle" picture makes more sense.